# Make DataGridViewColumn non hideable

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using `DataGridView` control in my **winforms** project. 
I have requirement to allow the user to edit this control: Hide/Show columns as he wants. 
However there are some specific columns that users are not allowed to hide.
I was looking at all properties of [DataGridViewColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx), it seems no one could help me out.

How can I make a  `DataGridView` column non hideable?

**Edit:**

Here is the full requirement that I'm trying to implement:

A user has the ability to right click a `DataGridView` and get new form listing all columns with check-boxes. So he can decide which column to hide and which column to keep by checking relative checkbox. 
I'm looking for a flag or property for non hideable columns so I can remove it from listed (editable) columns.

I don't like to hard code non editable columns because I have to do the same think across the hole application. I have around 10 `DataGridView`.

Comment: Strange question, just don't allow the user to "edit" that column.  Whatever "edit" might mean, it isn't exactly crystal.

Comment: @HansPassant I edited my question. I don't like to hard code "non-editable" columns as I have many DataGridView to configure

Comment: @Mhd Without "hard-coding", how do you (and your program) know which columns are supposed to be non-editable? Do you get this information from variables, settings, a configuration file, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Christopher said, you may have an array of columns to be set hidden and another for not allow hiding ones. You also have many DataGridViews, I suggest writing some public static methods then:

```
public static bool set_never_hide_column(DataGridView dgv, int[] col)
{
        try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn x in dgv.Columns)
            {
                if (col.Contains(dgv.Columns.IndexOf(x)))
                {
                    x.Tag = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    x.Tag = false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
}

public static bool set_hide_column (DataGridView dgv, int[] col)
{
        try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn x in dgv.Columns)
            {
                if (col.Contains(dgv.Columns.IndexOf(x)) && (bool)x.Tag == false)
                {
                    x.Visible = false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

*set_never_hide_column* use Tag property to set whether a column is hideable or not. This code will work based on column index.

So, for example, if I call *set_never_hide_column(your_dgv, new int[] {0})* and *set_hide_column(your_dgv, new int[] {0, 2})*, only the third column will be hidden.